# What are the processes involve in RDF management s for real-world data?

Tags: rdf, rdfs, rdfstore

Synthetic datasets like LUBM, BSBM, SP2Bench generated datasets have relational structure because of their structured classes. Therefore, they can be easily stored and query in RDF management systems. On the other hand, what are the challenges involved in storing and querying real-world data like Wikipedia. Can somebody give me a detail description of the storing and processing real-world data with an example?

Comment: Look at e.g. Wikidata. Though it is rather RDF mapping of data stored in the Wikibase data model...